# Rsync over SSH, who does the remote machine think I am

Tags: ssh, rsync

When rsync'ing over SSH to a remote system, who does the remote system think I am? I would have expected that as I rsync'd to user@remote.host, and then typed in user's password for that machine, I would look like, and have the privileges of, user on that machine, just as if I had logged in over SSH as user.

I have a file server machine running Mint 18 with some Tbyte disks that I use as a backup/archive, and rsync to periodically from my Mint desktop. In order to rescue files from my son's viralised win10 laptop, I started it from a Mint stick and attempted to rsync files to the server, but it failed with a write premissions error.

Did it think I was user, or does my identity from the client machine contaminate things at all? I didn't attempt to troubleshoot, but simply used a USB HD instead. Before I do try to understand it (for next time) what should I expect? What should I have done?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Please add commands you tried to execute. With comments which one worked and which one didn't. And where what did you expect. Also mount options for the partitions you attempted to write on target machine will also be helpful. Otherwise we can simply make wild guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `rsync` over `ssh`,

- An `rsync` target of `remotehost:` will use your local username to log in to `remotehost` unless the default has been changed in your local machine's `~/.ssh/ssh_config`.
- An `rsync` target of `remoteuser@remotehost:` will use `remoteuser` to to log in to `remotehost`.

Comment: I used the latter form of target. That's what I would have expected to have happened, which is why I was puzzled to have been refused permission. Now to try to replicate!

Comment: Solved, it was the mount options, the target drive was unmounted. I was confused that the error message was 'refused permissions', which is why I was asking who it thought I was.